# WordPress Gravity Forms - there was an issue creating your form error message

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I've been using Gravity Forms with no problems for a while, but today I'm receiving this error reading the following:

`There was an issue creating your form.`

Here is a screenshot of what the error looks like.

[image]

When I click on the *System Status* button to get more information, I see that the *Database* section has a red *x* reading the following:

```
The database is currently being upgraded to version 2.4.14.4. Current Status: Error Migrating Entry Headers: Table 'local.wp_rg_lead' doesn't exist NAN% complete. Force the upgrade
```

Here is a screenshot of the error above:

[image]

I click on the *Force the upgrade* button, but it has no affect on the issue.

Would anyone have any experience in solving this issue with Gravity Forms for WordPress? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I faced simillar issue on one of my sites but after sometime i manage to 
solve the issue by following steps.

1. Export gravity forms tables from database.
2. Export forms and entries from from wp admin
3. Drop tables of gravity forms from database.
4. Re activate/ install gravity forms in wp admin.
5. Import gravity forms and entries in wp admin.

   Thats it problem is solved and now you can create new gravity forms without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Uninstall** Gravity Forms via the plugin **General Settings** page (*Settings > Uninstall*)
2. **Reactivate** the plugin again via plugins page.

As of the time of this posting, GF does not drop tables on plugin reactivation or deletion via the plugins page.

Similarly it will not create the necessary tables on reactivation and even reinstallation after manual removal of problematic tables from the DB.

**GF will only drop tables after uninstalling via the plugin settings**, at which point GF will create the required tables again upon next activation or installation.

It's been this way for a long time now: https://legacy.forums.gravityhelp.com/topic/error-saving-form#post-70107